# setEnabled(false) does exactly what again?

Tags: android

I have a button in a View that I occasionally will call `setEnabled()` to disable and re-enable it. Worked fine.

Then I created an xml file for its `android:background` element to pretty it up, and the expected appearance for when it is disabled quit happening. It always looks enabled now, even when it is not.

I'm more than willing and able to create a `<selector>` that kicks in when it is disabled to get the expected behavior back, but I don't know precisely what that is. I believe there's some text color changes involved, but not sure what.

If I have to, I'll down the alpha to something "obviously disabled", but I'd like to get back what the stock behavior that was there before. Hoping someone can tell me what exactly happens to a View when it is disabled (aside from event handling)

This is the `<layer-list>`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gold"
        android:gravity="fill" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want to know what android does to a disabled button when the above snippet is NOT present. i.e. defaulting back the original android behavior when it is disabled.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
???????
    </item>
```

Comment: Attach some snippet. Specifically your `selector` xml.

Comment: I don't have a selector yet. As of right now it's just a `<layer-list>` that persists no matter what state the button is in. I want to know what, in effect, android does that would go into a selector for `<item android:state_enabled="false">`

Comment: added what I have to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_enabled" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    </selector>
```

And put the selector in your button's background:

```
<Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/selector" />
```

Comment: Without any reference to android:background, the button would have the default behavior when disabled. What is that? What do the drawable btn's correspond to?

Comment: You must indicate in button's background your drawable selector (first code)  and in the selector you must specify two drawables (one for enabled and other for disable)

You can check what is a drawable en the following [url](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/android_vector_assets.html)

Comment: Yes, I know! I want to know what to put in the drawable selector for disabled that would match it if I had no xml file referenced in android:background. There is a default behavior for not enabled that would occur without the selector. My problem is that I'd like to put it INTO a selector. What code would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. 
Whenever you enable the button  you can add

```
button.setEnabled(true);
button.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundofbuttonwhenenabled));
```

Whenever you disable the button  you can add

```
button.setEnabled(false);
button.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundofbuttonwhendisabled));
```

Comment: My question is when you don't have the selector, or any background set to it, you get the default behavior. What exactly is that default behavior? It seems to change TextColor, among other things.